# Finding a conformal map that sends unit disk to half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the conformal map that sends the unit disk $\{z | |z| <1 \}$ onto $\{z | Re(z) < 0\}$. I am having a lot of trouble with this kind of problems, actually coming up with such maps, so I would really appreciate if anybody could give me hints or tips to attack this kind of problems.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you only need to check 3 points because of the form Mobius maps take. Your answer should end being

$$\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

See if you can figure out why.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out.